# Show that n exists such that $f(\frac{1}{n}) \neq \frac{1}{n+1}$

Tags: complex-analysis

Let $U$ be a region in the complex plane that contains the closed disk $\overline{D(0,1)}$ and let $f: U \rightarrow C$ be holomorphic. I would like to show that there exists a natural number $n$ such that $f(\frac{1}{n}) \neq \frac{1}{n+1}$.

First. I noticed that $z=\frac{1}{n}$ can represent points inside $\overline{D(0,1)}$ and that $\frac{1}{n+1}$ can be rewritten as $\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} z^{k+1}$. Is it possible to show that this power series doesn't equal the function for a certain n?

Also, given that $\overline{D(0,1)}$ is compact, I think there's something that could be said about the uniform limit but I'm not sure whether that is relevant to this problem.

Could you please provide some directions as to how to approach this problem correctly?

Comment: Suppose that there is no such $n$. What can you say about $
f(z) - \frac{z}{{1+z}}$? (Hint: use the [identity theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Identity_theorem) on the open unit disc)

Comment: since $f(z) -\frac{z}{1+z}$ =0 on $D(0,1)$, by identity theorem, $f(z) = \frac{z}{1+z}$ over all U, and in particular, $\overline{D(0,1)}$?

Comment: Yes, which is a contradiction since $\frac{z}{1+z}$ is not holomorphic at $-1\in U$.

Comment: Ah! thanks, was a bit slow on the uptake but I finally got the idea of how to get the contradiction :)